# Bundler uses wrong path to ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gem-bundler

I have some problems running `bundle install`. I get messages like `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /bundler_cache/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out` and running `bundle install --verbose` showed me such output:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /bundler_cache/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:215:in `write_gem_make_out'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:135:in `build_error'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:174:in `rescue in build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `block in build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:747:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:299:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:143:in `block in install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:169:in `preserve_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:135:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:57:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:15:in `install_from_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:91:in `block in worker_pool'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:65:in `apply_func'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:60:in `block in process_queue'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `process_queue'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/worker.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
```

That output makes me worry: I use ruby 2.3.1, it is also specified in Gemfile. And bundler doesn't try to say that I use a wrong version, like it usually does. It just silently do it.

Is it wrong path, or it ok? What should I do?

`ruby -v` obviously provides not 2.3.0 but `ruby 2.3.1p112`

Comment: Are you using RVM? If so, did you install it as a different user? Check file permissions on the bundler_cache directory by running `ls -l` to see if your current login has permission to write.